# Solve Value Function Analytically

Tags: macroeconomics, mathematical-economics

The context is the Schumpeterian growth model with incumbent innovation (see Aghion, Akcigit, Howitt 2014 Handbook of economic growth): the value function is $$ r V_{t}(n)-\dot{V}_{t}(n)=\max _{z_{i} \geq 0}\left\{\begin{array}{c}
n \pi_{t}-w_{t} \zeta n z_{i}^{\eta} \\
+n z_{i}\left[V_{t}(n+1)-V_{t}(n)\right] \\
+n x\left[V_{t}(n-1)-V_{t}(n)\right]
\end{array}\right\} $$, where $n$ is the product lines that the firm holds, and all product lines have the same profit $\pi_{t}=\pi Y_{t}$, where $Y_{t}$ is the aggregate output.

Somehow it is straightforward to see that the value function is linear in $n$: $$ V_{t}(n)=n v Y_{t} $$ and $$ v=\frac{\pi-\zeta \omega z_{i}^{\eta}}{\rho+x-z_{i}} $$ is the average normalized value of a production line, where  $\rho=r-g$ and  $\omega \equiv w_{t} / Y_{t}$.

I don't understand how is this "straightforward"? And I wonder that in general when do we know that a value function  can be solved analytically like this?

---

My try:

To simplify the derivation, I drop $t$. So the value function is  $$r V(n)=\max _{z_{i} \geq 0}\left\{\begin{array}{c}n \pi Y-w \zeta n z_{i}^{\eta} \\ +n z_{i}\left[V(n+1)-V(n)\right] \\ +n x\left[V(n-1)-V(n)\right]\end{array}\right\}$$.

Conjecture that $V(n)=n\tilde{v}$.

Substituting into the original value function: $$r \tilde{v}=\max _{z_{i} \geq 0}\left\{\pi Y-w \zeta z_{i}^{\eta} + (z_{i}-x)\tilde{v} \right\}$$.

Assume $z_i^*>0$, this expression holds if $$\begin{aligned} \pi Y = & w \zeta z_{i}^{*\eta} \\ z_{i}^{*} -x = & r \end{aligned}$$, and $$ \eta w \zeta z_{i}^{*\eta-1} =  \tilde{v}$$.

Thus, the first condition requires that $$\pi Y = (w \zeta)^{\frac{1}{1-\eta}} (\frac{\tilde{v}}{\eta})^{\frac{\eta}{\eta-1}}$$ and the second condition requires that $$(\frac{\tilde{v}}{\eta w \zeta})^{\frac{1}{\eta-1}} -x = \rho +g$$.

In the equilibrium there is also a free entry condition: $V(1)=\tilde{v}=\psi w$, thus these conditions become $$\begin{aligned} \pi \frac{Y}{w} = \zeta^{\frac{1}{1-\eta}} (\frac{\psi}{\eta})^{\frac{\eta}{\eta-1}} \\ (\frac{\psi}{\eta \zeta})^{\frac{1}{\eta-1}} -x = \rho +g \end{aligned}$$.

Because in the BGP $g$ is a function of $x$, the second condition can be seen as a requirement on $x$. And the first condition is a requirement on $\frac{Y}{w}$, which is a constant in BGP.

But then how do I know that these two conditions hold in the equilibrium? Is this enough for the verification? And again in which way is this "straightforward"?